# RSA Java: Private Key cannot be used to encrypt

Tags: java, encryption

I am using RSA Algorithm for encryption and decryption of files. Currently, I have implemented the code on my local machine (Windows) and used private key to encrypt the file and public key to decrypt the same and it worked fine.

However, when I deployed my application to AIX machine than same approach thrown an exception that:

```
Private Key cannot be used to encrypt
```

I then checked in my logs that my java on windows machine is using `sun.security.rsa` security provider and Java on AIX is using `com.ibm.crypto.provider`

When I further surfed on internet I got to know that IBM does not allow in RSA to encrypt using private key.

Now the problem is that I do have to use private key for encrypton, but it requires to install or somehow embedd new security provider in my AIX Machine i.e. `sun.security.rsa`.

Can I do it in my existing code directly?
or can I somehow use private key for encryption using ibm package?
or any other way around? please help!

Comment: Normally, it is the public key which is used to encrypt and the private one to decrypt. If you do the contrary, anyone who gets the public key, which is easy as it is public, can decrypt your files...

Comment: You are right, but the message authenticity is also required as private key ensures that the file has been encrypted by the correct entity only! However, do you have any suggestion to overcome the provided issue please? I am quite worried.

Comment: You should use a signature approach then: you have your message, you create a signature with your private key you send the message and the signature the third party will be able to validate the signature against your public key.  If you need to encryt the message, you can encrypt the message with the public key of the third party. Usually, a symetric cipher is used to encrypt the message with a key that will be encrypted with the public key of the third party so that you will need to send the encrypted message, the signature and the encrypted key.

Comment: RSA is not for encryption, except for some small files. One can use [RSA-KEM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76857/18298) combined with AES-GCM. This will provide you Confidentiality, Integrity and Mutual authentication. If you want the signaturewith RSA then use a different RSA key pair and sign with RSA-PSS.

Comment: You forgot to attach your code. Also the first rule or reimplementing security algorithm is: _don't._ Use openssl which is available on both platforms. Edit: guess you're using a certificatr that doesn't have _data encryption_ as _keyUsage._

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869904/whats-wrong-with-ibms-jce-provider

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by using different JCE i.e BouncyCastle instead of IBM JCE.